# Run logon command as administrator Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, sysprep, windows-10, unattended

I've looked around and couldn't find a answer to this exact question. I am working on building a Windows 10 image to push to a bunch of computers using Clonezilla and I am trying to get the unattend process figured out for Windows 10. I have one that works in Windows 7 but for some reason Windows 10 functions differently. The specific problem is that the Logon Command I have running won't run with administrative rights and returns access denied errors. Since this is just a one time run to rename the computer Task Scheduler isn't really an answer. Is there a way to have the script run with admin rights at logon?

Edit: I've gotten a bit further by using some instructions found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/powershell-running-a-command-as-administrator However, I am getting a UAC prompt even though I am logged in a the Administrator account.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://serverfault.com/questions/753737/automatically-run-powershell-script-at-first-boot

Comment: Try disabling UAC prompt first to avoid the issue:     `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`